# div.childNodes.item(0) reconhece tabulação ou espaço como filho

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Uso o Ubuntu 13.10 e conheço poucos editores HTML para ele.

O editor que eu uso é o bluefish, que tem me ajudado muito. Estou aprendendo javascript pelo w3shcool e no momento estou na parte de DOM nodes, e como é um pouco mais complicado de entender, procurei um video na internet que me ajudasse a entender sobre nós, e achei um video explicando a "árvore genealógica" do html.

Quando eu testei o código a seguir:

```
window.onload = function()
{
   var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0);
   var ul = div.childNodes.item(0);
   Alert(ul);
}
```

imaginei que ele deveria retornar como `object HTMLULLISTELEMENT`; Mas está retornado como: object text.

Usando o firebug descobri que o problema é o espaço entre a div e a ul ou seja a tabulação que o editor bluefish dá ou é ele está considerando o espaço como texto.

Como posso resolver isso?

O video bem explicado sobre árvore (nodes) é esse:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruV-ZLn6gl8

O código completo abaixo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Core Api</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function()
        {
            var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0);
            var ul = div.childNodes.item(0);
            alert(ul);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Árvore</h2>

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li id="item1">
                Primeiro
                <span style="color:blue;">item</span>
                <ul>
                    <li id="item 1.1">item1.1</li>
                    <li id="item 1.2">item1.2</li>
                    <li id="item 1.3">item1.3
                        <ul>
                            <li id="item 1.3.1">item1.3.1
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>item2</li>
            <li>item3</li></ul></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Os nós do DOM podem ser de vários [tipos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType), incluindo nós de texto, que é o que você está encontrando. Você pode criar uma função para achar o primeiro nó do tipo `ELEMENT_NODE`. Algo assim:

```
function firstElementChild(nodeList) {
    var el = nodeList.firstChild;
    while(el && el.nodeType !== 1) {
        el = el.nextSibling;
    }
    return el;
}
```

No seu código, ela seria chamada assim:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0);
    var ul = firstElementChild(div);
    alert(ul);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/minewixo/1/edit

Porém, hoje em dia existe uma maneira muito mais simples de fazer isso, que dispensa essa função: [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), que aceita um seletor de CSS e retorna o primeiro elemento que coincidir com o seletor:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var ul = document.querySelector('div ul');
    alert(ul);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/minewixo/2/edit

Comment: Eu pensei em um if para resolver isso, o grande problema é que quando eu quiser usar o node de texto.Vou tentar esse método.